# Is count a property or not?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-2.0, google-style-guide

In the official google style guide for objective c, it's mentioned that

> Dot notation is idiomatic style for Objective-C 2.0. It may be used when doing simple operations to get and set a @property of an object, but should not be used to invoke other object behavior.

The following is the preferred way of getting/setting properties as opposed to using brackets:

```
NSString *oldName = myObject.name;
myObject.name = @"Alice";
```

The following is the non-preferred way of doing the same:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"hello"] retain];
NSUInteger numberOfItems = array.count;  // not a property
array.release;                           // not a property
```

However, according to the style guide, count is not a property and hence should use the bracket notation. However, count really is a property. Can anyone weigh in on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the documentation for `NSArray`, you'll see count is definitely a property

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/count

It sounds like the style guide just had a mistake.  As you said dot notation is preferred for property accessors-- but even more so with getters.  `array.count` is correct.

However it does make sense that mistake was made because in other languages, count is not normally stored as a property, and you would need to call a method to retrieve the count.  `NSArray` is special :)